# Qtablewidget- Row is not getting updated

Tags: c++, qt

Below is code which is in loop. The column is updating propelry but row is taking only 0th row. If row = 4, then also data is displayed on 0th row of table.

```
void method_1::set_data_ontable(int row, double l1, double l2, int type_of_object)
{
    setdes1->setText(QString::number((row), 'f', 0));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, 0, setdes1);
    setdes1->setText(QString::number((l1), 'f', 6));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, 1, setdes1);
    setdes1->setText(QString::number((l2), 'f', 6));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, 2, setdes1);
    setdes1->setText(QString::number((type_of_object), 'f', 0));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, 3, setdes1);
}
```

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Did you test the `ui->tableWidget` row count? try `ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(iRowsNumber);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set table [row count](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setRowCount)

> Sets the number of rows in this table's model to rows. If this is less than rowCount(), the data in the unwanted rows is discarded.

Answer (score 0):

It is working now. After changing the below

```
ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, 0, new 
QTableWidgetItem(QString::number((row))));

ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, 1, new 
QTableWidgetItem(QString::number((longitude), 'f',6)));

ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, 2, new 
QTableWidgetItem(QString::number((latitude), 'f', 6)));

ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, 3, new 
QTableWidgetItem(QString::number((row))));
```

new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number((row))). This new will not give any memory leak?.